# How do I save the .csv file where i converted the string data into numerical data of a specific column of a .csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wrote this program where i converted the string data into numerical data of the given rows. The actual csv file is [in here.](https://github.com/dsuborno/dsuborno/files/8802374/heart.csv)

```
> df.Sex[df.Sex == 'M'] = 1 df.Sex[df.Sex == 'F'] = 0
> #changing ChestPainType of TA ,ATA,NAP and ASY into 1,2,3 and 4 df.ChestPainType[df.ChestPainType == 'TA'] = 1
> df.ChestPainType[df.ChestPainType == 'ATA'] = 2
> df.ChestPainType[df.ChestPainType == 'NAP'] = 3
> df.ChestPainType[df.ChestPainType == 'ASY'] = 4
> # changing ExerciseAngina of N = 0 and Y = 1 df.ExerciseAngina[df.ExerciseAngina == 'N'] = 0
> df.ExerciseAngina[df.ExerciseAngina == 'Y'] = 1
> # changing RestingECG of Normal,ST and LVH into 1,2 and 3 df.RestingECG[df.RestingECG == 'Normal'] = 1
> df.RestingECG[df.RestingECG == 'ST'] = 2 df.RestingECG[df.RestingECG
> == 'LVH'] = 3
> 
> df.ST_Slope[df.ST_Slope == 'Up'] = 1 df.ST_Slope[df.ST_Slope ==
> 'Flat'] = 2 df.ST_Slope[df.ST_Slope == 'Down'] = 3 df.head()
```

and it is showing the output of the first 5 rows of [the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwG1.jpg)

but afterwards when i try to print the correlations using this program:

```
pearsoncorr = df.corr(method = 'pearson')   #df = the .csv file i am working with. 

pearsoncorr
```

the output it is showing me is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVxZk.png)

Here, I want to see the correlations of the new csv file i made changes earlier which should be [this file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX11p.png) and the expected correlation output should be almost [like this showing all the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZtAL.png). But this correlative table is showing me the correlations of [this](https://github.com/dsuborno/dsuborno/files/8802374/heart.csv) csv file.

The question is, How can i save the modified .csv file?

P.S. I am new in this site so if there are any errors I made, i apologize and i will be glad if you let me know how can i change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most probably trying to set the values on a copy of a slice from the DataFrame

> SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

You can see on [view-versus-a-copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) and [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://towardsdatascience.com/explaining-the-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas-ebc19d799d25) why this may be a problem.

When using `df.Sex[df.Sex == 'M'] = 1` the original DataFrame may not have been altered. You can check this using `df.info()` and inspect the `Dtype` column.

```py
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------          --------------  -----
 0   Age             918 non-null    int64
 1   Sex             918 non-null    object
 2   ChestPainType   918 non-null    object
 3   RestingBP       918 non-null    int64
 ...
```

In the previously mentioned link from Pandas documentation the recommended access method is using `.loc` for multiple items (using mask, `df.Sex == 'M'` in your case) and a single item using a fixed index:

```py
df.loc[df.Sex == 'M', 'Sex'] = 1
df.loc[df.Sex == 'F', 'Sex'] = 0
```

Another option would be to use Pandas [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), that, in my opinion better expresses the code intent.

```py
df.Sex = df.Sex.map({'M':1, 'F':0})
df.ChestPainType = df.ChestPainType.map({'TA': 1, 'ATA': 2, 'NAP': 3, 'ASY': 4})
df.ExerciseAngina = df.ExerciseAngina.map({'N': 0, 'Y': 1})
...
```

Cheking again for the `Dtype` column we can ensure that the values are in fact of type integer, allowing you to use `df.corr` (or save the Dataframe with the new values to a csv with [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

```py
Data columns (total 12 columns):
#   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------          --------------  -----
0   Age             918 non-null    int64
1   Sex             918 non-null    int64
2   ChestPainType   918 non-null    int64
3   RestingBP       918 non-null    int64
...
```